# Combine several separated images into one gallery

Tags: featherlight.js

I want to have one combined gallery for all images that have the `data-featherlight-gallery` option on one page.
In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/223/ there should be only one gallery with all six pictures in a row.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You must do a single binding with the correct filter, say [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/juersgyr/). Or bind it manually.

```
#
```

Comment: I use Ghost as a blogging platform and I add Featherlight via Javascript with jquery dynamically on document ready to images of a post. Normally those images are not placed right next to each other but I want to have one single gallery which contains all of the available images in a post. I cannot see how a filter helps in this regard: example https://www.peleke.de/comdirect-mit-datenloch-fremde-kontostande-einsehbar/

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to do that. Currently I use this script for post injection:

$(document).ready(function(){
    var img = jQuery(".post img");

    img.each(function() {
       var element = jQuery(this);
        var a = jQuery("<a />", {href: element.attr("src"), "data-featherlight": "image"});

        element.wrap(a);
    });
    $('.gallery').featherlightGallery();
});
</script>